# Getting MethodNotAllowedHere on AJAX call to Laravel controller

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to call controller from AJAX and there I got this error

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

I've tried a lot but not able to trace the actual problem.

Route.php

```
/*Ajax Request for Category*/
Route::post('category','AjaxOperationController@category');
Route::post('category/{category}', 'AjaxOperationController@category');
```

header.blade.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
           method:'post',
           url:'/category',
           data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
           success:function(data){
              //$("#msg").html(data.msg);
              alert(data.category_name);
           }
        });
     });
</script>
```

AjaxOperationController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;

 class AjaxOperationController extends Controller 
 {
 public function category(){
    $category=DB::select('select category_name from categories');
    echo $category;
    return response()->json(array('category_name'=> $category));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the csrf token to a meta:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Set up .ajaxSetup (This will be set in the default template so its included everywhere for other ajax requests):

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Your ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       url:'/category',
       success:function(data){
          //$("#msg").html(data.msg);
          alert(data.category_name);
       }
    });
 });
```

Keep track of your network tab in inspect element to see what response you get from the request, this will help debug further if anything else is going wrong

EDIT

Change your success response to:

```
success:function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#msg').append(data.category_name[i].category_name)
    }
}
```

Controller 
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Categories;

 class AjaxOperationController extends Controller 
 {
 public function category(){
    $categories = Categories::get();
    return response()->json($categories);
}
}
```

Comment: What does the network tab say in the preview section?

Comment: what error is it giving? Can you post your controller too

Comment: getting this error 
jQuery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:8000/category 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jQuery.min.js:4ajax
 @ jQuery.min.js:4(anonymous function) 
@ (index):39
i @ jQuery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jQuery.min.js:2
ready @ jQuery.min.js:2
K @ jQuery.min.js:2

Comment: ya posting give me a sec

Comment: If you return a string in the controller does the request go through?

Comment: need to check wait let me check :)

Comment: Did you see this part in the network:
http://imgur.com/a/OOlrA

 Once you click the 500 error you will be able to see more tabs with preview of the error

Comment: Click on the word category and then preview mate

Comment: is categories a model mate?

Comment: Remove this line:

echo $category

Comment: hey problem solved it was in echo $category now the AJAX call is returning an object so how should I convert it back to string from JSON in View??

Comment: yeah make it and also please make an edit to display the result in li tag I am newbie to laravel. Thanks bro! :)

Comment: in the response if you console.log(data) before the $.each what does it show? can you print screen it again mate

Comment: Also, see change to controller, if your models are in a model folder please edit the use App\Categories

Comment: I want to display that Romance and history category in li tag for dropdown menu!

Comment: Yeah i know, thats why in the $.each loop it outputs val.category_name <, you can pick them out from the model object

Comment: giving error expecting { is there any problem in () in function??

Comment: does it show the line? and have you console.log(data) on too?

Comment: if you get rid of $.each and console log on data does the error go away, and what shows?

Comment: the one that I have posted in image

Comment: in your controller try: return $categories

Comment: but where should i use inside controller?

Comment: return $category  returns undefined

Comment: sorry, $categories < my bad on the category haha

Comment: and make sure $.each is there

Comment: hey got it from json.stringify()

Comment: yeah.. even instead of json.stringify() all i need was   data.category_name[0].category_name thanks mate to solve this hell ! :)

Comment: now make necessary changes in your answer to loop along this data so that I could make a check on your answer :)

Comment: which did you use in the end json.stringify(data) ?

Comment: no I used data.category_name[0].category_name i guess simple for loop will do the trick here??

Comment: hey it returns nothing also i have try this and gives me what I need to 
for(i=0; i<=data.category_name.length;i ++)
               {
                    console.log(data.category_name[i].category_name);
               }
but it gives this error http://imgur.com/a/2sjgb

Comment: success:function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#msg').append(data.category_name[i].category_name)
    }
}

Comment: returns nothing mate.. although I've done in console.log for testing purpose.

Comment: in the controller is it just return $catagories?

Comment: ^ if it is try this: success:function(data) {
 $.each(data, function(index)) {
  $('#msg').append(index.category_name);
 }
}